# Installing an app to another device

Tags: android

I created an android app that works with my phone using android studio but if i send the app to another phone from my own phone, it doesn't install the app. Please how can i make the app install on a different phone without connecting it to android studio???

Comment: check the minimum sdk version of your code and phone.
and if you are installing app via USB? first enable it in settings o another phone.

Comment: What is the error you see while installing?

Comment: you may need to sign your app apk before installing on other phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are unable to install apk on other device because the apk you are sharing may be corrupted.

As app on your device was installed via adb(For example Android Studio may use Instant Run for quick changes) which is different than installing apps via Package Manager.

You can generate a debug apk as:
In Android Studio click on **Build > Clean Project** and then **Build > Rebuild Project**.

Now goto following path in your project folder:
**YourProjectFolderPath/app/build/outputs/apk**

There you can see .apk file. Copy that and send it to other devices.